# I don't understand the normalization of a quantum state in quantum machine learning paper

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, vectors, normalization

In the paper [arXiv:1307.0411](https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.0411) by Seth Lloyd, Masoud Mohseni, Patrick Rebentrost 
on page 3, line 8, it says: Constructing the $\log_2N$ qubit quantum state $| v \rangle = |\vec{v}|^{-1/2}\vec{v}$ then takes... etc. 
My question is then: Why is it:
$$| v \rangle = |\vec{v}|^{-1/2}\vec{v}$$ and not
$$| v \rangle = |\vec{v}|^{-1}\vec{v}?$$
I feel like $\langle v | v \rangle=1$ makes much better sense. What am I missing?

Comment: I apologize for @naturallyInconsistent. I suspect they had a vague recollection of setting $A=1/\sqrt{|\psi|^2}$ and thought that was what was going on here. Really shouldn't be throwing out such insulting comments after having paid so little attention to the question. Notice that the person asking the question is _right_ according to your assertion naturallyInconsistent. I think what's going on here isn't supposed to be normalization.

Comment: Sorry, AXensen is correct, I was dismissive and hasty. I think what is happening is still some form of normalisation, but that $\left < v \mid v \right > = N$ since it is supposed to be $N$ qubits

Answer (score 1):

In general, normalization is a somewhat arbitrary procedure, so the authors of the arxiv paper could have had their reasons for choosing this specific normalization, or this could be just their error, which could have or have not affected the following. Let me note that article [Phys. Rev. Lett. 114, 110504](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/274394406_Entanglement-Based_Machine_Learning_on_a_Quantum_Computer) , citing this arxiv article, uses a different normalization, coinciding with what you suggest (if I am not mistaken):

> The vectors can be represented with quantum states with a
> normalization factor, i.e.,
> $\vec{u}=|u||u\rangle,\vec{v}=|v||v\rangle$.